# Comodules of the $B,C$ and $D$ series quantum groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, comodules

In Section 11.5 of Klimyk and Schmudgen's book on quantum groups, explicit presentations of the isomorphism classes of comodules of ${\cal O}(GL_q(N))$ are given in terms of its "quantum minors". In the case of the other series of quantum groups, that is, the $B,C,$ and $D$ series, has anyone worked out such a presentation? Moreover, what about the exceptional quantum groups?